# MongoDB partialFilterExpression with document field comparisson

Tags: mongodb

I want to define a MongoDB [partialFilterExpression](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-partial/index.html) which is based on the comparison of two document fields. Specifically, it is about comparing two date fields. The index should only be effective if one date (here *processingTime*) is larger than the other date (here *creationTime*).

I tried it the following way but that does not seem to work (because the document are not removend via the TTL index condition).

```
db.
  getSiblingDB('foo').
  getCollection('bar').
  createIndex(
    { creationTime: 1 },
    {
      expireAfterSeconds: 60,
      partialFilterExpression: {
        processingTime: { $exists: true },
        processingTime: {$gt: "$creationTime"}
      }
    }
  );
```

I guess that `$creationTime` is not evaluated as a document field but only as simple text.

Is there a way to reach my goal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try storing a field in each document that contains the difference between the two date fields (e.g. `processing_creation_time_diff`) and then setting the `partialFilterExpression` on that value. For example:

```
db.getSiblingDB('foo').
  getCollection('bar').
  createIndex(
    { creationTime: 1 },
    {
      expireAfterSeconds: 60,
      partialFilterExpression: { 
        processing_creation_time_diff : { "$gt": 0 } // processing is greater than creation
      }
    }
  )
```

---

You are correct that the index specification as currently defined is evaluating `$creationTime` as a string. I threw together a quick example demonstrating that the filter expression is comparing `processingTime` against the string '$creationTime':

```
db.bar.insert({ "x" : "$before", "y" : 1 })
db.bar.insert({ "x" : "$compare_field", "y" : 1 })
db.bar.insert({ "x" : "$this_returns", "y" : 1  })

db.getCollection('bar').createIndex(
  { y: 1 },
  {
    partialFilterExpression: {
      x: {$gt: "$compare_field"}
    }
  }
);

db.bar.find({ "x" : { "$gt" : "$compare_field" }, "y" : 1 }).explain("executionStats")

// Returns only one doc using the partial index:
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5c342c9f1ed401160b81011d"), "x" : "$this_returns", "y" : 1 }
```

The partial filter expression is evaluated as `x is greater than the string "$compare_field"`, which matches the document with the value `$this_returns`.

Referencing a field using '$fieldname' is [typically used in aggregations](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/meta/aggregation-quick-reference/#expressions). Outside of aggregations you would need to use the [$expr operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/) which is not an operator that can be used for a [partialFilterExpression](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-partial/$g).

Comment: Thanks, especially for the workaround with the diff field. ;-)